# Laravel - Updating DB in Controller vs Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model that I require to update, such as `User`. In a large application, this `User` will also have relationships, and updating it would be more than a mere `User::find($id)->update(Input::all())`.

Should the updating be performed in the Controller, or be a method within the `User` model itself?

I always thought that I should put it in the model, since it is model specific. But I've seen most people perform the task in the controller. What is the reasoning for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the pattern names, the controllers control any model query or update. Based on this, the controller will be responsible for fetching, changing and saving the model.

If some actions are to be reused in many controllers, acting on a set of models, they would go in a "repository".

In your example, you are using Input::all() to hydrate your model, which you definitely have to change. Any user value has to be checked and/or sanitized. I would also recommend against using all and prefer either get or post, so you set up a minimal restriction.

So, I definitely let the controller be responsible for the "glue", having repositories for any collection matter,  services and hydrators to change the object, and the model itself staying for only getters and setters, managing their own data in their own scope.